# Builtin group membership not updating on client machines

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have a small active directory setup which is semi-live (i.e. being used by only a few of the computers in the network), however when i try adding members to the builtin groups, and more specifically the network operators group, it appears this has no affect on their membership to this group and associated rights are not being recognised on the client machine. When i perform a whoami /groups query it also doesn't show them in the group, while gpresults shows that all policies are infact up to date.

Additionally i have also tried adding other groups as members of the builtin group, and then give the user membership to that group, however this only shows them as being a member of the new group, though not the builtin group.

Would anyone know how to trouble shoot this or a suitable fix?

AD is running on windows server 2012, with a domain and functional level of 2012, the client machines are all windows 8 or windows 8.1

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're doing? When you say "adding members to the builtin groups", for example, are you talking about adding Domain user accounts into BUILTIN groups on member computers? Likewise, when you talk about "adding other groups as members of the builtin group" are you talking about creating Domain groups that you're adding to the BUILTIN groups on member computers?

Comment: Sorry i meant adding domain user accounts as members of the BUILTIN group.
As for the groups comment, i meant i created a new domain security group (universal) and added that new group as a member of the BUILTIN group.